# Bootstrap don't create node moduel folder via npm

Tags: node.js, bootstrap-4, frontend

I'm a beginner. I'm studying bootstrap, but when i'm trying install bootstrap via nodejs, the terminal annouced to me installing was successed, but node js don't create the node moduel folder in my project, so where is the node moduel folder? And how to create the node moduel in my project??
My english english!, i'm so sorry because of that
anyone can help me pls!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rM4mz.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest creating a `package.json` file to keep track of the dependencies that you install.

even after running `npm install bootstrap` it shows a warning to create the `package.json` file. and bunch of other warnings about peer dependencies needed for the bootstrap such as jquery.

One of the reason that your node_module is missing might be the version of the NodeJS that you are using.

Other one can be running out of resources to needed to complete the installation such as RAM. there is something similar [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/after-running-npm-install-installs-with-no-errors-node_modules-is-empty).